# Events only firing on specific machines but not on others

Tags: asp.net, events, master-pages, content-pages

I have been trying to solve this problem for several weeks now and it is getting really frustrating.  Basically i have a simple project which includes one master page and one content page. the following code is what is found in the content page

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="ButtonContent" 
        onclick="Button1_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

The button is bound to a simple event.  A break point is set to detect whether the event fired as expected.  The event does not fire when a form is placed above the content place holder.

```
 <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <form></form>
    </div>

    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <div>


    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

however the event is fired when the form is removed or place below the content place holder.  On the other hand, on some machines i have found that it does not matter if a form is placed before the content place holder. I have tried this project on 4 machines (three windows 7 and one xp) it has worked regardless of form placement on two machines and has been subject to form placement on the other two.

Could some one please point me to some setting which could solve this problem or offer any advice to solve my problem.  I need a form before the content place holder so removing is out of the question.  It would also make sense that some sort of setting is preventing the project from working correctly on another machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per HTML spec, you can not have form inside form. If I remember correctly some browsers break when you have this kind of structure. I think IE works fine.

If you need another form, put it outside of the <form id="form1" runat="server">
 - above it, specifically. That is valid.

Comment: I have tried this on IE, Chrome and Mozilla.  They all perform in exactly the same way on each machine...they either work or they don't.  This leads me to believe that the problem is not related to the browser but some machine specific settings.

Comment: why can't you just fix the HTML and make it valid? Then you can look at other issues

Comment: When u say fix the html, what do u mean exactly?  I am frustrated, however that the solution works one way on one machine and another way on another machine.  Do you have any idea what might be causing this behaviour

Comment: what i mean is that you can not have form tag inside another form tag.